# Finding roots of a polynomial using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import, module

Following code will find roots of a polynomial:

```
import numpy as np
print("Roots of the first polynomial:")
print(np.roots([1, -2, 1]))
```

But i cannot get output for roots if use:

```
import numpy as np
print("Roots of the first polynomial:")
print(roots([1, -2, 1]))
```

I assume since `roots` is a sub module,
we need to access roots using alias of `numpy` ie `np`;
I could not find in detail about `roots`, please share your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roots` is a function, not a submodule. When you call `np.roots`, you're accessing the function through the numpy module's namespace. Run `help(np.roots)` if you want to see more.

> `roots(p)`
>   Return the roots of a polynomial with coefficients given in `p`.

If you want to bring `roots` into your own namespace, you use the `from .. import ..` syntax:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import roots
```

Which imports numpy and brings the `roots` function into your own namespace so you can call it as you were doing so in the second snippet.